# Add page title as a javacript variable to specific posts

Tags: shortcode, page-specific-settings

I'm very new to WordPress and I'm sorry if this question may sound ridiculous.

I need a way to add the post title into it's content, only in specific posts, and not always at the same place in the content. I've done some research, but all I find is about changing functions in .php files or in *The Loop*.

I don't know if there are any kind of predefined functions, tags or code that can be used to print this type of information manually into the content. I tried including `<?php` code, but obviously is not the way as it gets commented (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Ps: This is intended to be used by content publishers, SEOs, and people knowing almost nothing about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). In your plugin or theme (`functions.php`) add:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_42534_add_permalink_shortcode' );
function wpse_42534_add_permalink_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode( 'permalink', 'get_permalink' );
}
```

Now, your users can use the string `[permalink]` anywhere in the post to print the URI to the current post or page.

Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: For the title would it be `'get_title'`? Is there any predefined shotcode? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can register any function which is returning a string as a shortcode callback handler. There are four predefined shortcodes: `[gallery]`, `[caption]`, `[wp_caption]` (an alias for `caption`) and `[embed]`.

Comment: In your theme it should be the `functions.php`. I made an edit to my answer to be more explicit. You may also just put the code in a separate file an drop the file in `wp-content/mu-plugins/`. It is an auto-loaded _must use_ plugin then.

Comment: thanks! I'm testing it, plugin will come later, as I go more through it

Comment: I cannot make it work, using `add_shortcode( 'title', 'get_title' );`, then posting [title]

Comment: Ok, it was `get_the_title`...

Comment: @Nacho: The second parameter of `add_shortcode()` is a function YOU define, not a builtin function.

Comment: @m0r7if3r It doesn’t matter where the callback function is defined. It just has to return a string.

Comment: @toscho I guess a better way of putting it would be that it's bad practice to use builtin functions.

Comment: @m0r7if3r Why? If you really need just the permalink there is no excuse to wrap the existing function into a container.

Comment: @toscho future proofing...do the extra little bit of work now so that you don't have to do it later.

Comment: @m0r7if3r The day `get_permalink()` stops working you have to touch the file anyway. No matter how you have defined the shortcode. Unnecessary overhead is a bad practice, reusing native functions is not.

Comment: @m0r7if3r I'm with toscho. If I had several places where I call get_permalink(), I could define a function myself wrapping it, but for what I'm doing is safe and fair enough. Also I think WordPress won't change built-in functions 'as easy' as you warn us, it'll be a HUGE mess to do so for tons of people...